# Understanding input/output in audio amplifier

Tags: circuit-design, audio, digital-audio

As I was trying to refurbish my Sony STR-434BS, I choose to install a brand new audio amplifier IC, specifically the TDA8954 as main chip for it's power deliver (around 100 [W] in stereo mode) and high-efficiency (doesn't need to be much, yet it's better than a 60% efficiency). Looking at the datasheet, there is a proposed schematic, which fulfill most of my needs. My question is: there are two input ports, each with a negative and positive terminal (IN1 and IN2). I have a RCA cable input as a proposed input, therefore I must design a differential signal input in this case? Bellow is the proposed schematics on the IC datasheet.

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting mono input to stereo/2 speaker output?

Comment: So you are replacing the existing IC with a TDA8954?  What is the original IC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the IC allows you to use differential input signals, it doesn't mean you have to. It's perfectly valid to just tie one side of a differential input to ground and drive the other side with a single-ended signal. Be careful with your current return paths, though, you don't want to have high power circuitry attached to the same ground as your sensitive low power signals.